# Creating .jar with source files in addition to .class files in bazel

Tags: gwt, bazel

I work with gwt. I am trying to use bazel with my project. I have several utility modules with gwt. How to create them so that sources will be included in them, so that they will be gwt compatible?

Comment: In case no one answers with a built solution I'd recommend you take a look at creating a macro which uses a java library and a genrule and the genrule depends on both source and bytecode outputs and repackages them together

Comment: Have you tried `resources = glob(["**/*.java"])`? Have you tried the https://github.com/bazelbuild/ruled_gwt

Comment: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_gwt

Comment: @ThomasBroyer I solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: > I solved the problem.

@KonstantinSolomatov How? Please share your solution!